# Is there any fork of the KinecticJS by the community which is going to be maintained and we can rely on it?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

We know that KinecticJS is no longer going to be maintained. From its GitHub page (https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/):

> Hi all! I will no longer be maintaining this repo or the official
>   KineticJS website because I have moved onto other ventures and
>   projects. The latest version of KineticJS, 5.1.0, is very solid and
>   can still be used in production applications. Please feel free to fork
>   the repo if you'd like to make changes.
>
> Also, you can now find tars of every stable KineticJS build on
>   www.kineticjs.com

Is there any fork of the KinecticJS by the community which is going to be maintained and we can rely on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was KineticJS original repo contributor. I maintain a fork: https://github.com/lavrton/KineticJS

I made o lot of things after last Eric's version. I already published two versions: https://github.com/lavrton/KineticJS/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md.

Also thinking about KineticJS organization.  https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/1055

**Update:** Fork is under new name **Konva** with repo: https://github.com/konvajs/konva